# Hierarchical Wordpress page nav with all permalinks in the root

Tags: wordpress, navigation, permalinks

Is there a way to have a hierarchical nav for Wordpress static pages without having the permalinks appear like they're in folders? I.e., I want nav structured like this:

```
+ Home
+ About
|- Me
|- My Dog
```

...with permalinks like these: /home, /about, /me, /my-dog. The only way I can find to set up navigation like this through Wordpress is to make the secondary pages children of the page above them, but this makes the permalinks look like this: /about/me, /about/my-dog

Is there any way (with a plugin or otherwise) to get all of the page permalinks linked from the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress 3.0 has a built-in menu creator.  you can customize the layout of your navigation regardless of how the pages are structured in the "Pages" section.

To solve your issue, have all pages be root pages and then rearrange them using the menu creator.

Comment: We don't even have the client whose site I asked this about anymore, but that's still good to know if it ever comes up again. Thanks.